# Performing Calculations WIth Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am in need of performing a calculation with a where clause based off two date fields in the joined two tables.  I have set-up the query like such, however the returned results I get are

```
SalesPerson SalesAmt    DiffAmt
G           22          -66
```

And my expected result set is

```
SalesPerson SalesAmt    DiffAmt
 G           11         -33
```

Below is sample DDL and the query I attempted to get my desired ouput.  What should be set-up differently in order to obtain my desired output?

```
Declare @Main Table (sn varchar(100), amt float, sd date)
Declare @Sub Table (sn varchar(100), samt float, ssd date)

Insert Into @Main (sn, amt, sd) Values
('G', 23.00, '20170601'), ('G', 21.00, '20170602'), ('G', 33.00, '20170608')

Insert Into @Sub (sn, samt, ssd) VALUES
('G', 11.00, '20170502'), ('G', 12.00, '20170601'), ('G', -1.00, '20170601')

Select
SalesPerson = m.sn
,SalesAmt = SUM(s.samt)
,DiffAmt = Sum(s.samt-m.amt)
FROM @Main m
Join @Sub s
On m.sn = s.sn
Where m.sd >= '20170601' And m.sd <= '20170605'
And s.ssd >= '20170601' And s.ssd <= '20170605'
GROUP BY m.sn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get aggregates before to join both tables.

> ```
> ;WITH g1 AS
> (
>     SELECT sn, SUM(samt) AS samt
>     FROM   @Sub
>     WHERE  ssd >= '20170601' AND ssd <= '20170605'
>     GROUP BY sn
> )
> , g2 AS
> (
>     SELECT sn, SUM(amt) as amt
>     FROM   @Main
>     WHERE  sd >= '20170601' AND sd <= '20170605'
>     GROUP BY sn
> )
> SELECT g1.sn AS SalesPerson,
>        g1.samt AS SalesAmt,
>        (g1.samt - g2.amt) AS DiffAmp
> FROM   g1
> JOIN   g2
> ON     g1.sn = g2.sn;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SalesPerson | SalesAmt | DiffAmp
> :---------- | -------: | ------:
> G           |       11 |     -33
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ac0c2cf205cbb0134065f60e34c1d322)*